# meteor vs derbyjs who is winning this battle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, derbyjs

Recently, I was looking for information about meteor and derbyjs and did not find too much about except an excellent derby's [article](http://www.slideshare.net/studgeek/an-overview-of-derbyjs-and-meteorjs-for-the-nova-nodejs-meetup?ref=http://studgeek.com/2012/07/11/nodejs-meteor-derby-overview-nodedc/?preview=true&preview_id=216&preview_nonce=4396a73077) that I would like to share with you. Besides all this I have very, very intrigued about both projects. I would choose one of them to test their effectiveness, speed and efficiency, what worries me now is that I want to implement jquery and bootstrap on the client and jade, nib stylus on the server. I want to know which one is faster. From what I read in the [article](http://www.slideshare.net/studgeek/an-overview-of-derbyjs-and-meteorjs-for-the-nova-nodejs-meetup?ref=http://studgeek.com/2012/07/11/nodejs-meteor-derby-overview-nodedc/?preview=true&preview_id=216&preview_nonce=4396a73077) i understand that derby is better, faster, and more compatible with SEO. but I want to know what opinions you have about the two projects.

I also read that meteor has a larger community, and have as much investment in the project so they have more support.

For now I just want to know what would be the best choice today.

thank you very much everyone, and I hope to get to the creators of the projects so that they can review the implementation of the modules of jade stylus nib, jquery and bootstrap for responsive design.

PS: I want to leave an important clarification, now my greatest strength is to express nodejs and npm ease allowing me to install any power tool and implement it in my projects.

Comment: As of today, 76 SO questions tagged Derby and 5,911 tagged Meteor. GG Derby, if you can't beat 'em join 'em.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are probably a thousand ways to judge this, if one is how active the community is, Derby has 41 tags/questions asked whereas Meteor has 1235 here on stackoverflow.

Because of this there are more packages that can help you build whatever you want, bugs are fixed faster & the framework is more stable. Initially derby had the leg up due it it having the MIT license. The meteor team however are very enthusiastic about building a fantastic framework also moved to the MIT license.

Also keep in mind that presentation was made in 10/12, Meteor's performance has advanced significantly since then.

With regards to scaling. I'm aware the Meteor team is building a method in which we can scale horizontally using a sort of DDP Proxy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oEPJGNNpkM

Regarding NPM modules & easy use, they're coming to meteor (you can use it now using the engine branch) : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA-QB9rQCq8

Routing (including server side routing) : Use Meteor-Router : https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router

Other links:

- http://blog.derbyjs.com/2012/04/14/our-take-on-derby-vs-meteor/ (from the derby team)

So urmm yeah.. choose Meteor =)

Comment: I used both Meteor and Derby. Derby is much more better.

Comment: I've used both for several months too (coding the same exact webapp). I agree with @VladimirMakhaev, Derby is much better. You'll find yourself fighting against Meteor as the webapp starts to grow. "Meteor does everything for you" is a poison in the long term. IMHO.

Comment: are you still of the same opinion?

Comment: @Nikos still the same opinion, lots of nice things have happened since this post too

Comment: @Akshat perhaps you should update links: IR instead of router, and recent performance changes such as oplog tailing and Blaze. Also numbers: 76 vs 5,911.

Comment: Using the number of questions as a metric is questionable, regardless of any underlying truths. By way of comparison, consider that the murder rate has dropped over time--but this isn't because gun (and other) violence is decreasing, but rather that medical technology, trauma care, and response times have increased. These days Meteor has more hype and momentum, which unfortunately counts for a lot (Java v. Smalltalk, anyone?)

Comment: AFAIK Derby is also integrating OT (Operational transformation) for conflict resolution...